# how to update files in android when connected to PC

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

i have an app that writes info whenever user hits record button & that works fine.
Now when I connect my device to PC and run the app, it still works fine and shows me the latest info on device but it does not update the file that I am viewing on my PC. 
How can I update(or refresh) my files every time after the file-writing is done ? (By the way, I am writing info on device's internal memory)

Comment: Huh?  Please think about rewording your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am accessing the same file both on android device & PC. Now, I run my app, it appends some content to that file & when I open the file on my device, it shows me updated info. But, when I open the same file on PC, it does not show me the latest info. is it clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to write to the SD card while it's mounted on your PC? When it's mounted on a PC, it gets unmounted on your phone due to the way its file system works, that's why this is happening.

Comment: I am writing on device's internal memory and not onto SD card.

Comment: Real SD card and internal memory behave the same: either you mount it on your PC or you can access it through Android. This said if you use ADB from your PC instead of mounting a disk, you can keep accessing the memory from the device.